# Should fixture.destroy() be explicit in Angular 2+ unit testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

For unit testing with Karma/Jasmine in Angular 2+, should the fixture destruction be explicit?

```
afterEach(() => fixture.destroy());
```

and what are the consequences if not destroying the fixture (i.e. is it called behind the scenes by the framework or does the fixture persist leading to side-effects)?

Angular [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ComponentFixture#destroy) on the topic don't suggest the right answer. What are your thoughts ? Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason you stumbled on this question?  Have you faced any issues in testing ?

Comment: I encounter both kinds of tests with explicit `fixture.destroy()` and without on a same project, but didn't find the answer in the documentation - is this needed or not. As an issue statement in safe terms - unnecessary repetition or missed destroys

Comment: and in not so safe terms (which I cannot link directly, so would prefer not to be considered for this discussion) periodic timers that go away when this statement is added and showing up when removed (without other changes), fyi - ticks, flushes and discarding of periodic tasks didn't fix the issue with timers in my case